# In a PDF, using C# and IronPDF library Is there a way to search for the table of contents and extract its hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, pdf, ironpdf

I'm working with some PDF's and I would like to extract its table of contents. Once I get it, I want to extract the hyperlinks that are inside or if it makes easier to understand: if I click on the content from the index, it redirects me to a page and to the part of the text that contains that header.

I've tried using every single class in IronPDF but I couldn't find anything to achieve what I wanted.
Is there any way? Or I'm trying the impossible? Do you know of other alternatives to this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, IronPdf are not currently possible to do that.